# Crawler4j authentication not working

Tags: java, http, web-crawler, httprequest, crawler4j

I'm trying to use the `FormAuthInfo` authentication from `Crawler4J` to crawler into a specific LinkedIn page. This page can only be rendered, when I am correctly logged.

This is my Controller with the access URLs:

```
public class Controller {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String crawlStorageFolder = "/data/";
    int numberOfCrawlers = 1;

    CrawlConfig config = new CrawlConfig();
    config.setCrawlStorageFolder(crawlStorageFolder);

    PageFetcher pageFetcher = new PageFetcher(config);
    RobotstxtConfig robotstxtConfig = new RobotstxtConfig();
    RobotstxtServer robotstxtServer = new RobotstxtServer(robotstxtConfig, pageFetcher);
    CrawlController controller = new CrawlController(config, pageFetcher, robotstxtServer);

    String formUsername = "session_key";
    String formPassword = "session_password";
    String session_user = "email@email.com";
    String session_password = "myPasswordHere";
    String urlLogin = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login";
    AuthInfo formAuthInfo = new FormAuthInfo(session_password, session_user, urlLogin, formUsername, formPassword);

    config.addAuthInfo(formAuthInfo);
    config.setMaxDepthOfCrawling(0);

    controller.addSeed("https://www.linkedin.com/vsearch/f?keywords=java");

    controller.start(Crawler.class, numberOfCrawlers);
    controller.shutdown();
}
```

}

And this is my Crawler class:

```
public class Crawler extends WebCrawler {
private final static Pattern FILTERS = Pattern.compile(".*(\\.(css|js|gif|jpg" + "|png|mp3|mp3|zip|gz))$");

@Override
public boolean shouldVisit(Page referringPage, WebURL url) {
    String href = url.getURL().toLowerCase();
    return !FILTERS.matcher(href).matches() && href.startsWith("https://www.linkedin.com");
}

@Override
public void visit(Page page) {
    String url = page.getWebURL().getURL();
    System.out.println("URL: " + url);

    if (page.getParseData() instanceof HtmlParseData) {
        HtmlParseData htmlParseData = (HtmlParseData) page.getParseData();
        String text = htmlParseData.getText();
        String html = htmlParseData.getHtml();
        System.out.println(html);
        Set<WebURL> links = htmlParseData.getOutgoingUrls();

        System.out.println("Text length: " + text.length());
        System.out.println("Html length: " + html.length());
        System.out.println("Number of outgoing links: " + links.size());
    }
}
```

}

When I run this app using the Auth, I get these errors:

```
    ADVERTÊNCIA: Cookie rejected [JSESSIONID="ajax:3637761943332982524", version:1, domain:.www.linkedin.com, path:/, expiry:null] Illegal domain attribute ".www.linkedin.com". Domain of origin: "www.linkedin.com"
jun 22, 2016 10:59:14 AM org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies processCookies

ADVERTÊNCIA: Cookie rejected [lang="v=2&lang=en-us", version:1, domain:linkedin.com, path:/, expiry:null] Domain attribute "linkedin.com" violates RFC 2109: domain must start with a dot
jun 22, 2016 10:59:14 AM org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies processCookies

ADVERTÊNCIA: Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie: lidc="b=TGST09:g=87:u=1:i=1466603959:t=1466690359:s=AQEc3R_6kIhooZN1RsDNkO2DaYEqzUWp"; Expires=Thu, 23 Jun 2016 13:59:19 GMT; domain=.linkedin.com; Path=/". Invalid 'expires' attribute: Thu, 23 Jun 2016 13:59:19 GMT
jun 22, 2016 10:59:14 AM org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies processCookies

ADVERTÊNCIA: Cookie rejected [JSESSIONID="ajax:4912042947175739413", version:1, domain:.www.linkedin.com, path:/, expiry:null] Illegal domain attribute ".www.linkedin.com". Domain of origin: "www.linkedin.com"
jun 22, 2016 10:59:14 AM org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies processCookies

ADVERTÊNCIA: Cookie rejected [lang="v=2&lang=en-us", version:1, domain:linkedin.com, path:/, expiry:null] Domain attribute "linkedin.com" violates RFC 2109: domain must start with a dot
jun 22, 2016 10:59:14 AM org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies processCookies

ADVERTÊNCIA: Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie: lidc="b=TGST09:g=87:u=1:i=1466603960:t=1466690360:s=AQE100NLG_uPIcJSJ7GLtRVkH7j_Ylu9"; Expires=Thu, 23 Jun 2016 13:59:20 GMT; domain=.linkedin.com; Path=/". Invalid 'expires' attribute: Thu, 23 Jun 2016 13:59:20 GMT
jun 22, 2016 10:59:14 AM org.apache.http.client.protocol.ResponseProcessCookies processCookies

ADVERTÊNCIA: Invalid cookie header: "Set-Cookie: lidc="b=TGST09:g=87:u=1:i=1466603960:t=1466690360:s=AQE100NLG_uPIcJSJ7GLtRVkH7j_Ylu9"; Expires=Thu, 23 Jun 2016 13:59:20 GMT; domain=.linkedin.com; Path=/". Invalid 'expires' attribute: Thu, 23 Jun 2016 13:59:20 GMT
```

Is this something related to the way how my http client deal with the cookie returned by LInkedIn?

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: This is not a problem of `crawler4j`. It is a problem of Linkedin, which they did not fix for a long time according to the latest google entries.

However, your approach will not work because `crawler4j` respects crawler ethics.
If you look at [robots.txt](https://www.linkedin.com/robots.txt), you will see, that the crawler will not crawl anything.